# How do I add the "Start Window" button to the toolbar?

Tags: visual-studio

In **Visual Studio 2019**, the **Start Window** button is missing.
How do I add the **Start Window** button to the toolbar?

**Pic-1**.
[image]

I expect.
**Pic-2**.
[image]

---

### Update-1

I did.
I don't have a **Start Window** button
How do I add a **Start Window** button?

[image]

---

### Update-2

**Note.**
The **Start Window** button used to be.
I don't understand why she disappeared.

**I did.**
I don't find the **Start Window** button.
Or am I wrong and just don't see her because of inattention?

**Pic-1**
[image]

**Pic-2**
[image]

**Pic-3**
[image]

**Pic-4**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the small "down arrow" icon at the right edge of the toolbar and select the "Add or Remove Buttons" command (usually, the *only* command) from the pop-up menu. That will show a list of command buttons that are – or can be – shown on the toolbar.

Make sure the "Start Window" (not sure what it's called in your language) command is checked (selecting the command will toggle it on/off).

Note that, although you have stated you have Visual Studio 2019, the icon that you've shown is the VS-2022 version. But that shouldn't make a difference: the procedure is much the same in both versions of VS.

[image]

Update:

If you don't see the "Start Window" command in the list of available buttons, then select the "Customize" command near the bottom of the list and, in the dialogue box that follows click "Add Command".

Then, in the next pop-up, select the "File" category in the left-hand pane and scroll down to get the "Start Window" command in the right-hand pane. Select that then click "OK":

[image]